# How to display categories in menu in the same order as in admin category tree?

Tags: magento2, topmenu, sort

I wonder if there way to have same sort order of categories in frontend menu as in admin panel category tree.

[image]

I thought position attribute should be used for this goal, but I've found that categories from level 3 and deeper have same position value as a parent, number on the screenshot is a position value

[image]

Comment: Could you find solution?

Comment: as I remember, it uses sort by default and the problem was in the custom menu.

Comment: I am using this code ````$childrenCategories = $this->getAllChildren($category);````  to load child categories of specific category but it's not showing in the order same as in adminpanel. Any idea?

Comment: you have to debug getAllChildren method and check sql query to see how order is formed.

Comment: Any one got answer for this?